# Problems with read only folders

Tags: files

I am attempting to do a full back up using grsync (I am using ubuntu 12.04. However some folders are read only - I have tried changing them in the permissions but this does not seem to work. Is there anything I can do in terminal to ensure all the sub foldlers and file in one specific folder have read/write access?

I've found these instructions but don't know where the hell to be begin: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FilePermissions

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running grsync from the command line with sudo? If that doesn't work you can change the permissions of a file like so:

```
sudo chmod u+w file.txt
```

The above will add write permissions for User to file.txt. However for sudo to work as intended you will need root permissions on your computer. Which if it is your personal computer I am assuming you do.